# Google Sheet Script: I want my "Date Created" column different from "Last Modified" column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have here a code for my google sheet script whereas when I type on my field, the date created will be fill up, but it will not be updated ever again, because when I want to update the field of a cell, I want to make my "Last Modified" the one to change, not the date created column. Thank you.

My code:

```
function onEdit(e)
{ 
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "GMQ LISTING") //"order data" is the name of the sheet where 
you want to run this script.
  {
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Date Created") + 1;
var dateModifiedCol = headers[0].indexOf("Last Modified") + 1;
var projectCode = headers[0].indexOf("Project Code (GMQ)  (manual)") + 1;
var gmqCODE = headers[0].indexOf("REFERENCE NO. (manual)") + 1;

if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == projectCode) 
{ 
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")); 
  
}

 if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == projectCode) 
{ 
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateModifiedCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")); 
}


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if-statement to something like

```js
if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == projectCode) 
{ 
  var dateCreated = sheet.getRange(rowIndex,dateCol).getValue();
  var stampCol = dateCreated ? dateModifiedCol : dateCol;
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, stampCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC+8", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")); 
} //end if-statment


}//end of function
```

I hope that helps?